# How can I classify some color to color ranges?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, rgb

If I get a lightgray color(for example R=G=B=200) and a dark one(for example R=46,G=41,B=35), I'd like to classify both of them to the simple gray color group(imagine a table).

So, how can I organize the colors to color groups?

Comment: what do you mean by organizing colors?

Comment: What groups of colors do you have?

Comment: I haven't decided that already. First of all, I want to create the algorithm. (But you can calculate with 50-60 group.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For visual classification of colors, it is often easier to convert the color to [HSL or HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) first. To detect grays, you check if the Saturation is below some threshold. To detect any other color, you check the Hue.

```
public string Classify(Color c)
{
    float hue = c.GetHue();
    float sat = c.GetSaturation();
    float lgt = c.GetLightness();

    if (lgt < 0.2)  return "Blacks";
    if (lgt > 0.8)  return "Whites";

    if (sat < 0.25) return "Grays";

    if (hue < 30)   return "Reds";
    if (hue < 90)   return "Yellows";
    if (hue < 150)  return "Greens";
    if (hue < 210)  return "Cyans";
    if (hue < 270)  return "Blues";
    if (hue < 330)  return "Magentas";
    return "Reds";
}
```

You could of course use some other divisions.

I made a simple JavaScript application to test this: [Color classification](http://jsbin.com/icixuy)

Comment: Hmm, thaks, I try it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to classify colors. One way would be to consider rgb to be a 3d coordinate and all possible colors could then be represented inside a box or cube with black in origo and white in the opposite corner located at (255,255,255). All grayish colors would then be located close to the diagonal. 
And red, green and bluish colors close to the axis. 
This way the classification problem has been transformed to finding the closest distance between a point (the color) and a line (the gray diagonal) in 3d space. If the distance is below a given threashold the color would be classified as gray.

Comment: Yes. Its basically the same thing as using the HSL/HSV representation but instead of a cube it has been transformed to a cylinder.

Answer (score -1):

How about below color table implementation:

```
public class ColorTable
{
    public Color ColorName { get; set; } //can set color code too
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

}
```

And write below code to generate/get color group:

```
//Generating Color Group Table
List<ColorTable> MyColorTable = new List<ColorTable>();
MyColorTable.Add(new ColorTable { GroupName = "Gray", ColorName = Color.Gray });
MyColorTable.Add(new ColorTable { GroupName = "Gray", ColorName = Color.LightGray });
MyColorTable.Add(new ColorTable { GroupName = "Green", ColorName = Color.Green });
MyColorTable.Add(new ColorTable { GroupName = "Green", ColorName = Color.LightGreen });

//Getting required Color Group, say "Gray"
List<ColorTable> GreenColor = MyColorTable.Where(c => c.GroupName == "Gray").ToList();
```

Comment: I just have passed color name, you could send color name with ranges, thanks

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't the answer for my question.
Imagine that you have a color, with the following RGB values:
55,83,70 (very dark green, almost gray)<br>
So, the question is, which group will contain this color? The green or the gray?
(So I don't have any pre-defined colors, classified to groups, only a few qroup name (with rgb values), for example greens and grays.)
<br><br>
But the RGB isn't required, it can be CMYK or hexa or anything, if it is easier.